# How to increase the EXT4 timestamp precision in linux?

Tags: linux, timestamp

Timestamp precision or accuracy of EXT4 filesystem in Linux is one second (
[Windows timestamp precision is 100 nano second](http://www.windowstimestamp.com/description) ). But our application which is running on cloud requires more precision for the filesystem . How to increase the timestamp precision in Linux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ext4 is supposed to support finer timestamps; it can depend on how the system was formatted:

- [timestamp accuracy on EXT4 (sub millsecond)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392975/timestamp-accuracy-on-ext4-sub-millsecond)
- [Determine file system timestamp accuracy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11599/determine-file-system-timestamp-accuracy)