# What's the right way to get the current time in python in a way that will be guaranteed to be consistent with the filesystem?

Tags: python, linux

I have a very simple build script that's behaving in an unexpected way (for me) on Linux.

Part of the script simply checks that the files generated by a build stage hasn't been manually replaced with a stale file.

```
# load the cache from a json file
if os.path.getmtime(some_path) < cache['timestamp']:
  print("build must run because %s is stale" % some_path)
  run_build = true

...

if run_build:
  cache['timestamp'] = time.time()
  # use subprocess to run process that modifies some_path
  # store updated cache to json file
```

Unfortunately, this naive logic isn't working on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04): the timestamp stored in the cache is often a few miliseconds ahead of the modification time on the generated files.

I could probably just round down the cached timestamp, but that just feels like a nasty hack, and I wonder if there's better way to get consistent times here.

Comment: @IsmailBadawi My current logic just has to manage a single timestamp, which is like because it's simple. Having to track separate timestamps for every involved file is extra complexity I do not necessarily need.

Comment: touch a file, use its timestamp?  That's basically how 'make' works.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Right now, neither.

Comment: As a side note, checking the modification time of a file isn't sufficient to find out if it's been modified. Moving or renaming a file doesn't change its modification time, so if you delete the original file and then move/rename a different file to that location, it won't trigger your build script.

Comment: @Rawing I think you are misinterpreting what that part of the script does, this is about detecting old files replacing new ones, not the other way around. I mean, it's technically possible to manually replace an output file with a random file that was created after the script last ran, but that's a not a scenario that should be possible without really looking for trouble.

Comment: If ext4, the lag in modification times may be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392975/timestamp-accuracy-on-ext4-sub-millsecond